# python: use sorted() function for dict inside the dict

Tags: python, dictionary

this is the dict I got now:

> dict1 = {1: {7: [6], 1: [7]}, 2: {3: [1, 6], 2: [2, 7, 5]}}

And I would like to order subdictionary by keys:

> dict2 = {1: {1: [7], 7: [6]}, 2: {2: [2, 7, 5], 3: [1, 6]}}

I tried some methods, but it didn't work...Like this one. Please help me.

```
print(sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]))
```

Comment: Items in a dictionary are not sortable because a dictionary has no concept of the keys being any particular order.  To print out a dictionary with the keys appearing sorted, you have to extract the keys to a list, sort that list, and then use the list to display each key in the dictionary.

Comment: @CryptoFool Wrong, dicts have been ordered for over four years now. Time to let go of that obsolete thinking :-)

Comment: Yeah I know... So I sorted the dict1.items(), but I don't know how to write the variable of key....

Comment: Wow.  I stand corrected.  Thanks Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use sufficiently high version of Python3 you can do:

```py
dict1 = {1: {7: [6], 1: [7]}, 2: {3: [1, 6], 2: [2, 7, 5]}}

dict2 = {k: dict(sorted(v.items())) for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(dict2)
```

Prints:

```py
{1: {1: [7], 7: [6]}, 2: {2: [2, 7, 5], 3: [1, 6]}}
```